# What can be done with Heroku H99 error?

Tags: node.js, heroku

Heroku production app (node.js) fails to start with H99 error for 1 hour.

According to documentation this error means 'heroku platform error' and is one of those that can't be fixed by app owner.

What can be done right now? Should I try fixing it somehow (rollback have already been done with no effect)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just wait and/or email Heroku support

Answer (score 2):

Hi little bit old but since it happen again,
The error definition is there : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h99-platform-error

So you can check heroku status here : https://status.heroku.com/